# variable is undefined in IE 11 using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have just started with Vue.js. I have a stripped down version of what I'm doing in jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/07uzLvum/2/. Works fine in Chrome, but in IE 11, I get 'c' is undefined' File: vue.js, Line: 2252, Column 36. I'm dynamically building a HTML table where the columns and rows are not known until runtime by querying a service. I've replaced the service calls with hard-coded values for the purpose of demoing in jsfiddle. Complete code below.

```
<div id="deliverables">
<div v-show="error" class="ProjectDeliverables_error">{{errorMessage}}</div>
<div class="ms-h2 ProjectDeliverables_loading" v-show="!loaded">Sit tight. Shouldn't be long now.</div>
<table style="width:100%;" v-show="loaded">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="ms-vh2" v-for="column in columns">{{column.title}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="deliverable in deliverables">
            <template v-for="c in columns">
                <td class="ms-vb2 edit" v-if="c.name === 'Edit'">
                <img src="blank.gif" style="cursor:pointer" />                        
                </td>
                <td v-else>
                    <span v-if="c.name === 'PFO_GatewayStatus'">
                    </span>
                    <span v-else>{{deliverable[c.name]}}</span>
                </td>
            </template>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#deliverables',
data: {
    deliverables: [
        {'Title': 'Test', 'Phase': '0', 'Start': '1/3/2016', 'End': '1/7/2016'},
        {'Title': 'Test 2', 'Phase': '1', 'Start': '1/8/2016', 'End': '1/12/2016'},
        {'Title': 'Test 3', 'Phase': '2', 'Start': '1/13/2016', 'End': '1/17/2016'},
    ],
    columns: [
        {'name': 'Edit', 'title': 'Edit', 'type': 'Computed'},
        {'name': 'Title', 'title': 'Title', 'type': 'String'},
        {'name': 'Type', 'title': 'Type', 'type': 'String'},
        {'name': 'Phase', 'title': 'Phase', 'type': 'String'},
        {'name': 'Edit', 'title': 'Edit', 'type': 'Computed'},
        {'name': 'Start', 'title': 'Start', 'type': 'DateTime'},
        {'name': 'End', 'title': 'End', 'type': 'DateTime'}
    ],
    loaded: true,
    error: false,
    errorMessage: ''
},
methods: {

}
```

});

Any idea what the issue is?

UPDATE based on responses. updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07uzLvum/3/
I needed to remove `<template>` and place the for each loop on the td tag.

```
<td v-for="c in columns" v-if="c.name === 'Edit'" class="ms-vb2 edit">
                    <img src="blank.gif" style="cursor:pointer" v-on:click="openEditForm(deliverable)" />
                    <i v-if="deliverable.Type === ''" v-on:click="" class="fa fa-line-chart sprint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" v-else>
                    <span v-if="c.name === 'Status'" v-html="getGatewayStatusImage(deliverable)">
                    </span>
                    <span v-else>{{deliverable[c.name]}}</span>
                </td>
```

This seems harder to read because of the v-if/v-else parsing I have to do. Looking at the code, I would've assumed the for loop would only loop through the first TD and never pick up the v-else TD, but it seems like for loop is hoisting outside of the TD.

Thoughts?

Comment: `<template>` is not allowed in IE. You'll have to do `<td v-for="..."></td>`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that certain DOM elements (like `<tr>`) have restrictions on what elements can appear within them – and this is browser specific.

It appears in this case that IE11 is eating the `<template>` tag.

See this for more information:

http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the code snippet was missing a close tag `</div>`.
Try checking if there are matching pairs of open and close tags.

Comment: No problem at all :)